# inquiry in designing my Arm simulator function representing format 1

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, thumb

The following function represents format 1 in ARM Thumb. I don't understand the part of using AND(&) after shifting in each declaration of the fields of the formats and why did we use these numbers after AND?
[format 1 representation in ARM architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q9Xy.jpg)

```
int simulate(unsigned short instr)
{
    unsigned char fmt, op, offset5, rd, rs, offset3, rn;

    fmt = (instr) >> 13;

    switch(fmt){
        case 0:             // format 1/2
            op = (instr >> 11) & 3;
            rd = instr & 7;
            rs = (instr >>  3) & 7;
            offset5 = (instr >> 6) & 0x1F;
            if(op!=3) {     // format 1
                /*
                switch(op){
                    case 0: printf("lsl\tr%d, r%d, #%d\n", rd, rs, offset5); break;
                    case 1: printf("lsr\tr%d, r%d, #%d\n", rd, rs, offset5); break;
                    case 2: printf("asr\tr%d, r%d, #%d\n", rd, rs, offset5); break;
                
                }*/
```

Comment: this is basic shifting and masking you can mask first then shift or shift first then mask, the end result is you have isolated some subset of the bits in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like `op`, it is supposed to be 2 bits long, but it's at some offset into your instruction. So you need to get the `op` bits shifted all the way to the least significant position, then remove any remaining bits.

The shift moves the bits to the least significant bit position in your `op` `unsigned char`, and ANDing that with 3 (which is `11` in binary, meaning only keep the 2 least significant bits) gets rid of anything in the higher bit positions (for `op` those should be all `0`s, but for something like `offset5` it would not be).

It's the same for each of the other parts of the instruction. `offset5` is 5 bits long, so we need `11111` in binary, which is `0x1F`, and so on.